# How to use the search() function in yii2 to search for more than 1 condition?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

In my controller in yii2 I have the following:

```
$searchModel = new HealthSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['HealthSearch'=>['zip'=>$zipcode]]);
```

which works but I would like it to also search for zipcodes and speciality

I tried:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['HealthSearch'=>['zip'=>$zipcode,'pri_spec'=>$sspec']]);
```

but that does not work? What is the correct way of searching??

Comment: you have a php syntax error. remove the last `'` .

Comment: Show us your search model code

Comment: Apart from the typo, the code looks correct. You usually don't create that array yourself, it comes from the HTTP request: `$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams)`.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the last single quoted `'`.  Your code should work fine. An easier to read version may look like :

```
$searchByAttr['HealthSearch'] = [
    'zip' => $zipcode,
    'pri_spec' => $sspec
];

$dataProvider = $searchModel->search($searchByAttr);
```

Also you need to check the `HealthSearch` class which is the first responsible of making that search. **Gii** generates a primary boilerplate  from your model that need to be adapted to your app in further steps. By default the `HealthSearch::search()` method should filter by all model's safe attributes and as any `ActiveRecord` class it has also a `rules()` method that returns those safe attributes. So if `zip` and `pri_spec` are not included in that array they will be simply ignored.